# Editing Embedded Javascript in html page using chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

asking again the question [Using Google Chrome to debug and edit javascript embedded in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497913/using-google-chrome-to-debug-and-edit-javascript-embedded-in-html-page)

if there is a Javascript embedded in html page can i edit it .in this question he accepted an answer.In this answer's second comment by antyrat "Well you're right, but you can edit this at Elements tab instead." but when i edit javascript in script tag changes doesn't affect code flow.Please guideline is it possible to change embedded js in html page in chrome dev tools or not ??

Comment: Any javascript code will be built by browser when the page is opened/loaded and just the only one time. You can edit but I think your new code will be not execute.

Comment: no it gets executed if u edit using breakpoint in pure js file but not in html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to the javascript in a page using chrome developer tools but those changes do not get saved. You will need to manually go and change it in the respective .js file for the changes to take effect. Only if you want to preview the change temporarily, you can try those with the chrome developer tools